# Rstore postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am trying to restore a PostgreSQL database that consists of two different schemas. I am using pg_restore for the restore process. However, I am encountering errors due to dependencies between the schemas, resulting in "relation doesn't exist" errors.

Is there a way to control the order in which objects are restored? For example, I would like to restore schema 1 tables first, then schema 2 tables, followed by schema 1 views, schema 2 views, and so on. This would help resolve the dependency-related errors during the restore process.

If there is no built-in mechanism in pg_restore to control the restore order of specific objects within schemas, what alternatives or workarounds can I employ to overcome these errors and ensure a successful database restore?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. `pg_dump` dumps the object so that no dependencies between the objects in the dump are violated, but two dumps cannot do that. One thing you could try is to restore both dumps repeatedly. That will lead to a lot of errors, but eventually all objects should be created. And unless you have a table without primary key, there shouldn't be any duplicate data either.

Comment: Should work automatically. How did you create the dump?